# can we only install x-pack for kibana, not install for elasticserach?

Tags: kibana, xpack

Unhandled rejection [illegal_argument_exception] No endpoint or operation is available at [_xpack] :: {"path":"/_xpack","statusCode":400,"response":"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"No endpoint or operation is available at [_xpack]\"}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"No endpoint or operation is available at [_xpack]\"},\"status\":400}"}
    at respond (/opt/gfitps/TpsStream/kibana-5.0.1-linux-x86_64/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:289:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/opt/gfitps/TpsStream/kibana-5.0.1-linux-x86_64/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:248:7)
    at HttpConnector. (/opt/gfitps/TpsStream/kibana-5.0.1-linux-x86_64/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:164:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/opt/gfitps/TpsStream/kibana-5.0.1-linux-x86_64/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4962:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)

Comment: I installed elasticsearch5.0.1  .  kibana5.0.1 .  x-pack5.0.1 just for kibana

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/current/installing-elastic-stack.html) you should install for both. and the same version for all.